# Accept multiple arguments in an AS3 method

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, methods, arguments

How do I accept multiple arguments in a custom method? Like:

```
Proxy(101, 2.02, "303");

function Proxy(args:Arguments){
    Task(args);
}

function Task(var1:int, var2:Number, var3:String){ 
    // work with vars
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to just pass the args array through like you have in your question. You'd have to pass each element of the args array seperately.

```
function Proxy(... args)
{
   // Simple with no error checking.
   Task(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
}
```

**Udate**

After reading one of the comments, it looks like you can get away with:

```
function Proxy(... args)
{
    // Simple with no error checking.
    Task.apply(null, args);

    // Call could also be Task.apply(this, args);
}
```

Just be careful. Performance of apply() is significantly slower than calling the function with the traditional method.

Comment: Are you sure there's no way to pass an array of arguments which gets translated to the inbuilt arguments by AS3? Or is there a cleaner way of writing the Task function so I don't have to use `arg[0]` and `arg[1]` ?

Comment: This method seems most correct. If you need to pass an unknown number of arguments you can use the apply method on the function as well.

_obj.methodName.apply(_obj, [arg1, arg2, arg3]);

Comment: Here is the documentation on the apply method.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Function.html#apply%28%29

Comment: -1 This actually won't work for constructors as the poster suggests. Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874869/can-i-use-apply-with-constructor-to-pass-arbitrary-number-of-parameters

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `apply(thisArg:*, argArray:*):*` method from the `Function` object.

example:

package{

```
    public class Test{
          public function Test(){
              var a:Array=[1,"a"];
              callMe.apply(this,a);
          }       
          public function callMe(a:Number,b:String):void{
                trace(a,b);
          }
    }
}
```