# Can I use apply() with constructor to pass arbitrary number of parameters

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, constructor, new-operator, apply

I've got a function wich can accept a varible number of parameter with a rest operator.

I want create an object passing the argument collected with the rest operator directly to a constructor without create an object and call an initializing function and without passing the entire array but the parameters ah I do with apply() function.

Is it possible ? Using apply doesn't work.

```
public function myFunc(...arg) {

     // something link "new MyClass.apply(args)"
     return new MyClass();

}
```

Comment: I was sad to see this could not be done, since I am extending Array to make a `ConstantArray`, removing all ability to add and remove from it once it was created via the constructor. Guess I could still do `super.push()` within a for each loop, :( not as nice as doing `super.apply(this, rest)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately no. There is no way to make apply work for constructor. What is done generally is to prepare a number of call based on the number of arguments :

```
public function myFunc(...arg):Myclass {
  switch (arg.length) {
    case 0:return new MyClass();
    case 1:return new MyClass(arg[0]);
    case 2:return new MyClass(arg[0], arg[1]);

    //... etc

    case n:return new MyClass(arg[0], arg[1],..,arg[n]);
    default: throw new Error("too much arguments in myFunc");
  }
}
```

Comment: ouch!! my factory methods now start to suffer

Answer (score 2):

Well this led me to an interesting long research!

I found this neat SWC file filled with utils for mimicking the AS2 eval():
http://www.riaone.com/products/deval/index.html

And here's a proof of concept that what you're looking for might actually work:

```
package tests {
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;
    import r1.deval.D;

    public class RandomTests extends Sprite{

        public function RandomTests() {
            super();

            var test:BitmapData =   create(BitmapData, 100, 100, true, 0x00000000);
            trace(test);
        }


        public function create( pClass:Class, ... pArgs ):* {
            D.importClass(pClass);
            var fullQName:String =  getQualifiedClassName(pClass);
            var qNameSplit:Array =  fullQName.split("::");
            var className:String =  qNameSplit[1];
            fullQName =             qNameSplit.join(".");

            var statements:String =
            "import $0;\n" +
            "return new $1($2);";


            var args:Array =        [];
            for (var a:int = 0, aLen:int = pArgs.length; a < aLen; a++) {
                switch(pArgs[a].constructor) {
                    case String:
                        args[a] =   "\"" + pArgs[a] + "\"";
                        break;
                    default:
                        args[a] =   pArgs[a];
                        break;
                        //throw new Error("Unhandled type, please add it: " + pArgs[a].constructor);
                }
            }

            return D.eval(XString.gsub(statements,[fullQName, className, args.join(",")]));
        }
    }

}
```

Sorry for the bits of dependencies (Like my XString class for easy sub-replacements) but it does work in theory. The only issue would be passing object references as argument entries. But then again... the r1.deval.D class might be able to take it... hmm.

Anyways, thought maybe this would be worth sharing.

Comment: I recalled this answer today after some issue I ran into with instantiation for embedded BitmapData. CS4 seems to require the "new YourBitmap(-1, -1);" constructor parameters, and CS5 doesn't - "new YourBitmap();". Kinda irrelevant, but I started thinking... hmm, maybe the SWC from r1.deval.D is fooling us into thinking it can handle ANY number or constructor parameters.
 I mean... who knows, maybe they just do Patrick's approach internally (hardcoded constructor parameters based on arguments length).  Would really like to extract their code to see how dEval was able to do this.

Comment: D.eval will only handle 20 parameters. Despite the sophistication of the library, they're doing the exact same thing that the original question suggested. This is what CallExpr.newInstance() is doing. Feel free to test it out with a class that has more than 20 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

well there's also this

```
public function myFunc(args:Object) {

   //then access various argumens
   return new MyClass(args.name, args.id, args.active)

}
```

and call it through `myFunc({id:33,name:'jo')`

you could then pass the object, or is this too far from what you're looking for?

Comment: not to far, passing a dynamic object or a VO class was my first workaround. I was curious to know if was possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching for the answer too, but too sad to see the answer is no....

Here's my current (not so good) way to do this kind of stuff, hope some of you interest:

```
// Foo.as
public class Foo {
    // construct
    public function Foo(... args):void {
        create.apply(this, args);
    }

    // this function do as a really construct function, tricky stuff
    function create(id:uint, name:String) {
        trace(id, name);
    }
}

// Bar.as
// for create this kind of class, just new it as usual
...
var foo:Foo = new Foo(123, "abc");
...
```