# how to create an instance from a string with unkown number of parameters in constructor in actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3

I know I can create instances from a string like this:

```
var classFromClassPath:Class = getDefinitionByName(classPath) as Class;
var instance:Object = new classFromClassPath()
```

I know I can call some function with a parameter array like this

```
var x:Function = someFunction;
x.apply(null,args);
```

But does anyone know if I can pass parameters like that when I construct a class?

Comment: Brievly, no you can't pass arbitrary parameter to dynamically construct your class, check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874869/can-i-use-apply-with-constructor-to-pass-arbitrary-number-of-parameters/3875599#3875599