# class reflection in adobe flex

Tags: apache-flex, reflection, inversion-of-control

I am a Java programmer who is learning Adobe Flex.

Is it possible to do the kinds of reflection that I can do in Java (get the constructors of a class, get the parameter list of a constructor, invoke the constructor with a given set of parameters) in Flex?

If so, can someone point me to an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate a class in this way

```
var classN:Class = getDefinitionByName("package.goes.here::ClassName") as Class;
var instanceClass:Object = new classN();
```

use describeType to access properties

```
var sourceInfo:XML = describeType(instanceClass);
var objectProperty:XML;
var propertyName:String;
//loop through the accessors
for each(objectProperty in sourceInfo.accessor) {
    if(objectProperty.@access == "readwrite") {
        propertyName = objectProperty.@name;
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I ask a constructor for its parameter list? How do I invoke the constructor with those parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer from @Tostis:

1) You can use the class object (instead of the instance object) to get the object information:

```
var classN:Class = getDefinitionByName("package.goes.here::ClassName") as Class;
var sourceInfo:XML = describeType(classN);
```

2) The information returned for a Class object includes a <factory> tag, with all the information including the constructor (in the <constructor> tag) and its parameters.

If you use an instance class, the same data is available but not in the <factory> tag.  But then, if you want this to instantiate the objects dynamically, you wouldn't have an instance object to start with...

**Update**

I did a check through StackOverflow, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874869/can-i-use-apply-with-constructor-to-pass-arbitrary-number-of-parameters) reference - short answer, it doesn't look like there's a good way to call the constructor with an arbitrary parameter list, like Function.apply() allows.