# Passing arbitrary number of parameters to a function in AS3

Tags: function, actionscript-3, flash, parameters

How do I pass an arbitrary number of parameters to a function?

When calling an unknown function (from a String), I want to pass parameters to that function. The parameters are stored in an Array:

```
var arr:Array = ["param1","param2"];
```

There could be any number of elements in `arr`. There could be any number of parameters allowed in the function as well, and the numbers could be different from each other.

So far I've been doing this to call the function:

```
this[functionName](parameter);
```

But this only allows for one parameter. How do I get all of them in regardless of how many are required?

Edit: To be clear, I want to access the function the same way, but I don't know how many parameters it might have. I want to dump an array of parameters into an unknown function. I'm not sure how many parameters the function has, and I'm generally assuming the length of the array is equal to the number of parameters in the function (an error will be thrown if anything goes wrong, which is fine).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accept multiple arguments in an AS3 method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914648/accept-multiple-arguments-in-an-as3-method)

Comment: Use the array as the parameter?

Comment: I don't want to use an array as a parameter in all my functions. I'm going to be accessing possibly dozens of functions and using an array is an ugly hack I don't want to get bogged down in.

Comment: @akmozo yep, this is a duplicate. sorry about that. i do think mine makes more sense and the correct answer by fsbmain is a more concise answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that use [`Function#apply()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#apply()) method.

For your example:

`this[functionName].apply(null, arr);`

Answer (score 0):

Another method that might do the trick is this:

```
function myFunction(arg:String, arg2:String, ... args)
```

`args` is not a keyword.  Then call the function like:

```
 myFunction("foo","bar","sink",12,);
```

I just found this yesterday and used it to pass keyframes of animation like this:

```
function animateChar(o:Sprite, startFrame:int, rec:Rectangle, ...keyFrames):void
    // loop like keyFrames is an Array
    trace(keyFrames[i])

and called it like this:

animateChar(character,5,myRec,{f:3,t:2},{f:2,t:2},{f:1,t:2});
```